# $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sum_{i=1}^ni^{4\lambda}}{\Big(\sum_{i=1}^ni^{2\lambda}\Big)^2}=0$

Tags: limits, sums-of-squares, gauss-sums

Is it true that $\forall \lambda>0$ $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sum_{i=1}^ni^{4\lambda}}{\Big(\sum_{i=1}^ni^{2\lambda}\Big)^2}=0$$
I cannot find a way to prove it, nor can I find a counterexample. 
Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: For $k>0$, $$\sum_{i=1}^n i^k\sim\frac{n^{k+1}}{k+1}.$$

Comment: To calculate, use Cesàro--Stolz theorem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The numerator is less than $n\cdot n^{4\lambda}.$ In the denominator there are at least $n/2$ terms that are at least $(n/2)^{2\lambda}.$ Thus our expression is less than

$$\frac{n\cdot n^{4\lambda}}{[(n/2)(n/2)^{2\lambda}]^2}.$$

This is on the order of $\dfrac{1}{n}$ as $n\to \infty,$ hence the limit is $0.$